# many postgres.exe processes show on RAMMap with 4k private bytes

Tags: django, postgresql, windows-server-2016

Here's my software environment

> OS: `Windows Server 2016 version 1607`
> Database: `PostgreSQL 12.12`
> Backend application: `Django 4.0.8`
> RamMap: `v1.61`

I have memory leakage issue on this server and tried using RamMap to find out what's possibly cause this problem. As you can see in the attached image below, I have a lot of `postgres.exe` listing on the `Processes page` with pid and 4K Private bytes, but none of these shows up in Task Manager screen.

All clients access PostgreSQL use `http POST` via my `Django` backend application installed on other server.

I've tried some ways but fail:

1. `taskkill /f /pid <PID>` did not work since they're not show in Task Manager.
2. restart PostgreSQL service but theses zombie processes were still there.
3. slow down clients access speed but these processes were still increasing.

I have no idea how can I do to kill these processes. Could anyone give me some instructions to solve this problem? or the zombie processes is not even an issue that they will just there and have nothing to do with memory leakage?

After running this query script:

```
 SELECT state, backend_type, count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity GROUP BY state, backend_type ORDER BY backend_type, state;
```

I have

| state | backend_type | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | autovacuum launcher | 1 |
| NULL | background writer | 1 |
| NULL | checkpointer | 1 |
| active | client_backend | 1 |
| idle | client_backend | 1 |
| NULL | logical replication launcher | 1 |
| NULL | walwriter | 1 |

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These processes are client backends; they are the server side of a database connection. You terminate these processes by closing the database connection on the client side. So if you want to get rid of these processes, find and fix the connection leak in your application. And please don't ask how to do that – it is your application code.

On the other hand, why do these processes bother you (unless you are hitting `max_connections`)? 4kB of memory is very little, unless you happen to run PostgreSQL on a toaster.

Comment: it bothers me because when I run the server for months, the memory usage goes up to 100% and shut down all the applications. It happened couple times. BTW I do have PostgreSQL `max_connections = 100` however these process numbers are way more than 100

Comment: These processes are not what uses all your memory. Run the following: `SELECT state, backend_type, count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity GROUP BY state, backend_type ORDER BY backend_type, state;`, edit the question and add the result there.